# Using callback ref to modify scrollLeft property in React

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a container div with a lot of children, and an overflow-x set to scroll.

This allows me to scroll the content to the left and right using my trackpad (or drag on mobile).

But I really would like the default scroll position to be the maximum horizontal value. (i.e. scrolled all the way to the right). The relevant code for this is `Element.scrollLeft = <some large value>`.

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve this with React and callback refs. I have the following code:

```
const containerRef = useCallback(
  (node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      node.scrollLeft = values.length * 20;
    }
  },
  [values.length]
);
return (
    <div className={"scroll-wrapper"} ref={containerRef}>
      values.map(()=>{
        // Some stuff in here that's irrelevant.
      });
    </div>
)
```

(This code was based on https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node)

When I put a breakpoint in the useCallback function, I see it is properly invoked with a non-0 value, but right after the call when I inspect `node.scrollLeft` it is still 0.

When I inspect the DOM in Chrome, I can actually force the `scrollLeft` of the element to be high number, which does work.

So why doesn't the React useCallback ref work?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to work with refs.

To create ref use this:

```
const containerRef = useRef();
```

And add it to `ref` of `div` as you did before:

```
<div className={"scroll-wrapper"} ref={containerRef}>
  ...
</div>
```

And you should use `useEffect` and call it one time to set `scrollLeft` to the component in ref:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ref.current.scrollLeft = 4000;
}, []);
```

Here is the full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-glitter-s0gok?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and while it is correct, so is my original code. I actually find the useCallback approach a bit more elegant as you get a direct reference to the node itself. This does actually work.

I tried your answer and I got the same results. After long debugging it turns out the problem was unrelated. It was due to an animation framework I'm using that created elements with a delay + in combination with absolute positioning of my child elements. I'll update the question for it to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed

then just make some css issue for that

```js
  const [scrollX, setScrollX] = useState({
    side: ""
  });
  const scrollLeftRef = useRef();
  const handleScroll = (data) => {
    setScrollX(prev => ({ ...prev, side: data.side }));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollX.side === "right") {
      scrollLeftRef.current.scrollLeft += 200;
    } else {
      scrollLeftRef.current.scrollLeft -= 200;
    }
  }, [scrollX]);
```

```html
   <div class="slide-sample">
            <div id="slideRight" onClick={() => handleScroll({ side: "left" })} class="preSlide">
              <i className="fas fa-caret-square-left" />
            </div>
            <div ref={scrollLeftRef} class="slideouter">
              <div class="slideinner srcl">
                <ul>
                  {
                    categories.map((category, i) => {
                      return (

                        <Button
                          key={category.id}
                          onClick={() => { dispatch(filterfood(category.name)); handleItemClick(i) }}
                          variant={activeclass === i ? "contained" : "outlined"}
                          size="medium"
                        >
                          {category.name}
                        </Button>
                      )
                    })}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="slideRight" onClick={() => handleScroll({ side: "right" })} className="nextSlide">

              <i className="fas fa-caret-square-right" />
            </div>

          </div>
```